# How to prove a sequence does not converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I want to show that the sequence $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}+(-1)^n$$ does not converge to a limit.

I know that if a sequence $\left( a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to a limit L, then $\forall\epsilon >0\;\;\exists N\in\Bbb N \;\text{such that}\;\forall n\geq N, \;\;|a_n-L|\leq\epsilon$, but I am not sure how to use this to prove a sequence that does not converge to a limit.

Please give me some suggestions on where can I get started and how to write out the proof, thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: check the limit for $n$ odd and $n$ even.

Comment: @Lucy: Your sequence is a sum of two parts. How each one of them behaves as $n$ tends to infinity? How will their sum behave?

Comment: You can easily show that $a_{n+1} - a_n$ goes to 2. If the sequence converged it would have been 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a sequence $\{ a_{n} \}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ converges to a limit $L$, then every subsequence must converge (can you prove this part on your own?), and the subsequences must all converge to the **same limit** (can you prove this part on your own?).

But it is easy to prove that the subsequence $\{ a_{2n} \}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ of even indices converges to $1$ (can you do this on your own?) while the subsequence $\{a_{2n - 1} \}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ of odd indices converges to $-1$ (can you do this part on your own?).

Because of this, the sequence does not converge since it has two subsequences that converge to different limits.

Answer (score 6):

Yo can prove that $a_n$ isn't Cauchy sequence. According the definition $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence if:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \, \exists N \in \mathbb N \, \forall n,m \geq N \; |a_n-a_m|<\varepsilon$$

But for $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ the difference between $a_N$ and $a_{N+1}$ is:

$$\left| a_N-a_{N+1} \right|= \left| \frac{1}{N}+(-1)^{N}-\frac{1}{N+1}-(-1)^{N+1} \right|=\left| 2 \cdot (-1)^{N}+\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N+1} \right| \geq \\ \geq \left| 2 \cdot (-1)^{N} \right| - \left| \frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N+1} \right| \geq 2 - \frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{N+1} \geq \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $\;\lim a_n=L\;$ exists, then

$$(-1)^n=a_n-\frac1n\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\stackrel{\text{Arith. of limits}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=L-0=L$$

But it is clear that $\;\{-1,1,-1,1,\;\ldots\}\;$ doesn't converge...

Comment: Would you please explain the workings a bit more?

Comment: What isn't clear, @Lucy? The first equality in the second line follows from the definition of $\;a_n\;$, the following from arithmetic of limits...

Comment: Sorry, I was just confusing myself earlier. I understand now, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Lucy , my pleasure .

Answer (score 2):

The subsequences $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ have different limits so the sequence $(a_n)$ is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, if we choose $\varepsilon=\frac{1}2$, we would be able to find some $N$ and $L$ such that every term of $a_n$ with $n>N$ would be within $\frac{1}2$ of $L$. This is impossible, since odd terms, for $n>2$ are always less than $-\frac{1}2$ and even terms are always greater than $\frac{1}2$. Therefore, if an interval of size $\frac{1}2$ contained every even term, it could not contain any odd term and vice versa - implying that the limit cannot exist.