# Start of a proof

Tags: limits

Can anyone suggest a way to start off a proof to show that the limit of (-1)^n is divergent? I have no idea where to begin on this one

Comment: What's your definition of convergence? Can you show that it *doesn't* hold?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the definition is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove a sequence does not converge?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981064/how-to-prove-a-sequence-does-not-converge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem:**  A sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ converges if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that $|a_m - a_n| < \epsilon$ for $m,n \ge N$.  (A sequence satisfying this criterion is called *Cauchy*.)

Using this result (you only need the "$\Rightarrow$" direction, which is the easier one to prove), the divergence of $\{(-1)^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a one-liner.

Edit with further details:  (This is assuming that your class is one where limits are defined precisely with the $\epsilon$ stuff.)  To prove "$\Rightarrow$" in the above theorem, assume $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ and let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.  By the definition of limit, there is a positive integer $N$ such that $|a_n - L| < \epsilon/2$ for $n \ge N$.  So, for $m,n \ge N$ we have: $$|a_m - a_n| = |(a_m - L) + (L - a_n)| \le |a_m - L| + |L - a_n| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon.$$  (The first inequality is the Triangle Inequality.)  With that proven, it is now very quick to show that $\{(-1)^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge.  Simply note that $|(-1)^N - (-1)^{N+1}| = 2$ for any positive integer $N$, so the above condition for convergence cannot hold.

Comment: This is exactly where I got lost. My teacher has done a very poor job of explaining this I feel like he just threw something like this on the board and said " do it just like that". Can you explain this theorem to me? I'm not entirely sure why we need all of these variables.